# LocationSettingsRequest dialog to enable GPS

Tags: android, location, android-gps, google-location-services

From past few days I am looking for a solution but unable to find any. I am working on a situation when the google location accuracy is toggled off for android 9+ then the application should prompt user to toggle on the location accuracy.

**Problem facing:**

Is it possible if (statusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED) then navigate directly to google location accuracy screen of the device(which looks difficult). *OR* customise the dialog box which is prompted by google services library (which is not possible i assume). Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Below is the snippet.

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();     mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest).addOnSuccessListener(mActivity,
        new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        mFusedProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


            }
        });
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(mActivity, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED){
            //Location settings not satisfied.
            try {

                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                        mActivity,
                        LOCATION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
    
            }
        } else {

        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,works for me

```
private void showLocationDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(RequestLocationUpdatesWithIntentActivity.this).setTitle("The location service is not enabled on the phone.")
            .setMessage("Go to Settings > Location information (enable location service).")
            .setNegativeButton("cancels", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Unset", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    try {
                        RequestLocationUpdatesWithIntentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                        try {
                            RequestLocationUpdatesWithIntentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

You can call it here.
[image]

And then there's this effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. you are the best :)

Comment: hi,Is this helpful ?  Please accept this answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks :)